# Twitter Stream API to Collect Tweets

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I want to collect tweets with some specific information. Consider hash tags. I want to collect some specific hash tag. The tweets are 15 days old and even today there are fresh tweets regarding it. I was wondering if there is any API with the example so as to do this process. I would like to collect the tweets in Json format and then process it to store to the db.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Search API of Twitter.

`http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23Twitter`

Where `#Twitter` hashtag is encoded in URL.

I asked a similar question, this would be helpful for you. [Whether to choose Search or Streaming API of Twitter for public geo-tweets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378294/whether-to-choose-search-or-streaming-api-of-twitter-for-public-geo-tweets)

Comment: But what about the older tweets how to iterate so as to get the tweets that are fifteen days old any method?

Comment: Twitter will give you a week old tweets (not sure about days). Search API gives you the same data that you can get from Twitter web search. If you want very old tweets, might be you have to consider other alternates. e.g. Topsy.